# Formula for the Negative binomial inverse cumulative function

Tags: probability

For example, how many times ($N$) do I need to flip a coin ($p=0.5$) to have a $P=90\%$ probability of having observed $20$ heads. I empirically found that I need $N=20+28=48$.
Is it correct?

Is there an explicit formula for the Negative binomial inverse cumulative function?

Comment: If you have MATLAB, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/nbininv.html

Comment: I use Maple (statevalf,idcdf,negativebinomial) but I would like to know if there is an explicit formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $F(k) = P(X \leq k) = 1-I_{p}(k+1,r)$ where $I_{p}(k+1,r)$ is the [incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html). So $0.9 = 1-I_{0.5}(k+1,r)$. From this, I believe you have enough information to get $k$ and $r$ and hence $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I know how to compute the incomplete beta from k and r but I can not see how to compute k and r from the value of the incomplete beta.
what did I miss?